# CSS media queries not working in inspect dev tools, works just fine in normal view

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hello I am building a react app blog, when I use it in normal view, the page behaves fine, and when I shrink it's width to the pixels the items look as intended. However when using dev tools my page looks completly different, has added blank space and horizontal scroll even with  `overflow-x:hidden;` in the body.

I have checked zoom and its 100% for each view.

I have added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

in the head of my main html, and it just messes the entire thing up, like I said hozontal scroll and everything is massive.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navLinksOpen {
        margin-top: 4em;
        padding-left: 2em;
        gap: 1em;
        width: 100%;
    }

    button {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    .navList {
        font-size: 4em;
    }

}
```

Media querie in question,I just started to build it to make mobile look more responsive. Do not know what else to add, frustating  at the fact of not knowing pixel width when editing.

First image is just a screenshot from browser, second is in inspect with no viewport(not picking up media queries), last is with the viewport meta in head, and just looks completly different from what I am building. Any help is very apreciated, or if its time for a new browser.

Also to add each one is set to the mobile S selection with 100% zoom

[image: Photo of nav bar on its own]

[image: Photo without viewport]

[image: Photo with viewport in head]

Answer (score 0):

I believe I fixed it. added this to body

```
  position:absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

And tried this again

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

With a few other minor tweaks like setting max widths on stuff. I got it working again, thank you. I hope this can help future people